# How to make a Cron-job for smart search

Tags: joomla-3.x, smartsearch

When setting up a Cronjob for smart search the links from search results goes to blank pages. When indexing manually everything works. What am i doing wrong?

Sending the command

> php [URL]/cli/finder_indexer.php

Memorylimit 256 MB

Comment: The Smart Search, in its current incarnation, puts a lot of pressure of the website from multiple angles, it is a better idea to disable it and use Sphinx instead. See this comprehensive guide on how to do that: https://www.itoctopus.com/using-sphinx-to-substantially-enhance-the-speed-of-the-joomla-search . Using Sphinx instead of SmartSearch will reduce the load on the server substantially especially on high traffic sites with lots of content.

Answer (score 1):

You should be executing that based on the file path, not a URL

Say the file is located in /var/www/html/cli/finder_indexer.php

Your cron job should execute: php /var/www/html/cli/finder_indexer.php

Running it manually, you should see output like this:

```
Smart Search INDEXER
============================
Starting Indexer
Setting up Smart Search plugins
Setup 5 items in 0.068 seconds.
 * Processed batch 1 in 0.311 seconds.
Total Processing Time: 0.38 seconds.
Peak memory usage: 10,485,760 bytes
```