# Cannot set up Cron Task for Smart Search in Joomla 4 - Alternative

Tags: joomla-4.x

I am trying to create a cron task for the search index in Joomla 4. The PHP file is also called, but an error occurs.

I created the cron tasks according to these instructions:

- https://docs.joomla.org/Setting_up_automatic_Smart_Search_indexing
- [How to make a Cron-job for smart search](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16782/how-to-make-a-cron-job-for-smart-search)

And it looks like this:

```
php -d memory_limit=512M httpdocs/cli/joomla.php finder:index
```

And this is the error:

```
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\UndefinedFunctionError {#164
  #message: "Attempted to call function "simplexml_load_file" from namespace "Joomla\CMS\Language"."
  #code: 0
  #file: ".httpdocs/libraries/src/Language/LanguageHelper.php"
  #line: 614
  trace: {
    .httpdocs/libraries/src/Language/LanguageHelper.php:614 {
      Joomla\CMS\Language\LanguageHelper::parseXMLLanguageFile($path)
      › // Try to load the file
      › $xml = simplexml_load_file($path);
      › 
    }
    .httpdocs/libraries/src/Language/LanguageHelper.php:516 { …}
    .httpdocs/libraries/src/Language/Language.php:203 { …}
    .httpdocs/libraries/src/Language/LanguageFactory.php:35 { …}
    .httpdocs/libraries/src/Language/CachingLanguageFactory.php:45 { …}
    .httpdocs/libraries/src/Service/Provider/Application.php:130 { …}
    .httpdocs/libraries/vendor/joomla/di/src/ContainerResource.php:176 { …}
    .httpdocs/libraries/vendor/joomla/di/src/Container.php:96 { …}
    .httpdocs/cli/joomla.php:75 { …}
  }
}
```

Presumably this function is simply for security reasons (unfortunately I hadn't realised at first that different PHP installations are used within the provider's Cron Task UI).

Are there alternative ways to make the indexer work automatically?

Comment: It means XML is disabled on your PHP installation. Perhaps CLI/cron is using a different PHP installation or configuration than the web server. Ask your host.

Comment: My CRON jobs for Joomla CLI follow this format:

/usr/local/bin/php /home/{account}/public_html/cli/joomla.php cache:clean -n -q

You could look in Joomla Administrator under System > Information > System Information > PHP Information to see if SimpleXML is enabled.

Comment: The file is found (the path is correct) and SimpleXML is also enabled.

Comment: You can always just try running a little php script with just one line $xml=simplexml_load_file('filename of an xml file'); and see if that returns an error or not.